# If two representations have the scalars a its commutants, why does it imply that they are either unitarily equivalent or disjoint?

Tags: representation-theory, von-neumann-algebras

In Kadison's article he says that:
"Since the commutant of an irreducible representation consists of scalars, two such are either unitarily equivalent or disjoint."
Ref:”https://msp.org/pjm/1960/10-2/pjm-v10-n2-p12-s.pdf”

That the commutant of irreducible representations consist of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{1}$ I got as a result of considering the subspace generated by the commutant of a irreducible representation $\pi$ (of a Banach $*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$), then using the irreducible property of $\pi$, the fact that $\pi(\mathscr{A})'$ is a von Neumann algebra and that every von Neumann algebra is generated by its lattice of projectors (the projectors of $\pi(\mathscr{A})'$ were proven to be $0$ and $\mathbb{1}$ only).
I am really terrible at representation theory, so for me that phase seems really disconnected, if two representations have as commutant $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{1}$ why are they either unitarily equivalent or disjoint (i.e. have no unitarily equivalent sub-representations)?

Comment: Subrepresentations correspond to invariant subspaces, or equivalently projections in the commutant. A trivial commutant is then equivalent to saying there is no subrepresentation except the trivial ones. (Of course, this is also just the definition of irreducible representations.) So if two irreducible representations are not unitarily equivalent, they must be disjoint.

Comment: Why is a trivial commutant equivalent to saying that there are only trivial subrepresentations?

Comment: A subrepresentation is a subspace that is invariant under the action of the algebra, right? A subspace corresponds to its orthogonal projection. I’ll leave it to you to show that $H_0 \subset H$ is invariant under $\pi(A)$ iff $p_{H_0}x = p_{H_0}xp_{H_0} = xp_{H_0}$ for all $x \in \pi(A)$ iff $p_{H_0}$ is in the commutant of $\pi(A)$. So, projections in the commutant of $\pi(A)$ correspond to invariant subspaces, i.e., subrepresentations.

Comment: As you have observed, the commutant of $\pi(A)$ is densely spanned by its projections, so the commutant of $\pi(A)$ is trivial iff the only projections in the commutant of $\pi(A)$ is $0$ and $1$ iff the only subspaces invariant under $\pi(A)$ are the zero subspace and the entirety of $H$, iff the only subrepresentations are the zero representation and the entire representation itself, i.e., only the trivial ones.